# Windows authentication under custom domain

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I have a site using windows authentication. it's working fine by calling the site like http://serverName/appName; but it's not for http://intranetDomain/appName.

Other application hosted on the server use login page, this is my first application on the server with windows authentication. How should I configure IIS to make it working.

Thanks so much

Edit: the problem is user will be asked to sign in to access the website.
Sign in message: your connection to this site is not private.
if I refuse to sign in, it will give me: 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

more info: anonymous authentication disabled, windows authentication enabled. If I enable anonymous authentication, the problem will be gone, but windows authentication won't work.

Comment: The title does not match the question. Also you need to provide more details (error messages or else) than "it's not".

Comment: @Lex Li, I added more info, thank you

Comment: What's the browser you use? Internet Explorer should prompt in this case, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/258063/internet-explorer-may-prompt-you-for-a-password

Comment: i tried 3 different browser, chrome, firefox and ie, all same. @Lex Li, thank you

Comment: Thank you @Lex Li to hinted me. I configured out, I added the domain in Intranet Site on user's pc. Everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

That's because Keberos authentication was enabled when you access the website via domain name. It sounds like your KDC don't have permission to authenticate token for your intranet domain. So please ensure you have registered SPN for your domain.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929650/how-to-use-spns-when-you-configure-web-applications-that-are-hosted-on

Answer (score 0):

To someone has same problem like me, anonymous authentication disabled, windows authentication is on and NTLM is on top of list in provider, extended protection on, and enabled Kernel-mode; but sign in window still popup.

Added your domain to Intranet Site on user's pc